# ORACLE SQL PROCEDURE WITH FOR LOOP AND IF ELSE ERROR

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I need to replace employee id in shift table for a particular day with another employee id who hasn't any shift for a particular day.
This my tables,

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE
        (EMPLOYEE_ID NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
        NAME VARCHAR(50),
        GENDER VARCHAR(10), 
        BIRTH_DAY DATE,
        PRIMARY KEY(EMPLOYEE_ID)        
        );
CREATE TABLE SHIFT
        (SHIFT_ID NUMBER(4),
        SHIFT_DATE DATE,
        CUSTOMER_ID NUMBER(4),
        SERVICE_ID NUMBER(4),
        EMPLOYEE_ID  NUMBER(4),
        SHIFT_CHARGE FLOAT(10), 
        PRIMARY KEY(SHIFT_ID),
        FOREIGN KEY (EMPLOYEE_ID) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(EMPLOYEE_ID)  
        );
```

For the above purpose, I want to create a  procedure. I created the procedure is below. But there is a compilation error.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CHANGE_SHIFT_SHEDULED
 (
    EMPLOYEE_ID IN SHIFT.EMPLOYEE_ID%TYPE,
    SHIFT_DATE IN SHIFT.SHIFT_DATE%TYPE
 )
 AS
    CHECK_CON BOOLEAN:=TRUE;
 BEGIN
    FOR SICK_EMP_SHIFT_REC IN (SELECT * FROM SHIFT WHERE SHIFT.EMPLOYEE_ID=EMPLOYEE_ID AND SHIFT.SHIFT_DATE=SHIFT_DATE)
    LOOP
        FOR EMP_REC IN (
                SELECT e.EMPLOYEE_ID,COUNT(e.EMPLOYEE_ID)AS SHIFT_COUNT,
                CASE
                    WHEN SHIFT_COUNT>0 THEN FALSE
                    ELSE TRUE
                END AS SHIFT_COUNT
                FROM EMPLOYEE e LEFT OUTER JOIN SHIFT s ON e.EMPLOYEE_ID=s.EMPLOYEE_ID 
                WHERE s.SHIFT_DATE=SHIFT_DATE 
                GROUP BY e.EMPLOYEE_ID)
        LOOP
            CHECK_CON:=EMP_REC.SHIFT_COUNT;
            IF CHECK_CON THEN
                UPDATE SHIFT s SET s.EMPLOYEE_ID=EMP_REC.EMPLOYEE_ID WHERE s.SHIFT_ID=SICK_EMP_SHIFT_REC.SHIFT_ID;          
                EXIT;
            END IF;
        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
 END;
 /
```

Please anyone help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not looking at logic you applied; I *hope* you did it right. I just fixed errors which prevented code you wrote to compile; for example:

- don't name parameters as column names; use some prefix, e.g. `par_` or `p_`
- in cursor FOR loop, you can't have two columns with same name (`shift_count`); one has to be changed
- also, you can't use an alias in the same statement's `CASE` (which is what you did with `shift_count`)
- Boolean support is somewhat *strange* in Oracle. For example, there's no such datatype at SQL level. Therefore, you'll have to work with strings or numbers, and then "convert" them to Boolean (e.g. line #26)

The rest is OK, I suppose.

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE change_shift_sheduled (
  2     par_employee_id  IN shift.employee_id%TYPE,
  3     par_shift_date   IN shift.shift_date%TYPE)
  4  AS
  5     check_con  BOOLEAN := TRUE;
  6  BEGIN
  7     FOR sick_emp_shift_rec IN (SELECT *
  8                                  FROM shift
  9                                 WHERE     shift.employee_id = par_employee_id
 10                                       AND shift.shift_date = par_shift_date)
 11     LOOP
 12        FOR emp_rec
 13           IN (  SELECT e.employee_id,
 14                        COUNT (e.employee_id) AS shift_count,
 15                        CASE
 16                           WHEN COUNT (e.employee_id) > 0 THEN 'FALSE'
 17                           ELSE 'TRUE'
 18                        END
 19                           AS shift_count_case
 20                   FROM employee e
 21                        LEFT OUTER JOIN shift s ON e.employee_id = s.employee_id
 22                  WHERE s.shift_date = par_shift_date
 23               GROUP BY e.employee_id)
 24        LOOP
 25           check_con :=
 26              CASE
 27                 WHEN emp_rec.shift_count_case = 'FALSE' THEN FALSE
 28                 ELSE TRUE
 29              END;
 30
 31           IF check_con
 32           THEN
 33              UPDATE shift s
 34                 SET s.employee_id = emp_rec.employee_id
 35               WHERE s.shift_id = sick_emp_shift_rec.shift_id;
 36
 37              EXIT;
 38           END IF;
 39        END LOOP;
 40     END LOOP;
 41  END;
 42  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
```

Comment: thank you soo much, now compiled it. you saved my time lot. thank u again.

Comment: You're welcome. As you were already told: on Stack Overflow, "thank you" is best expressed by upvoting and/or accepting answers that help you.